# Create & write a file which is having 'execute' permission?

Tags: dart

I'm writing a `bash` script with dart.

Below code create a file. but that file doesn't have 'execute' permission.
so I'm not able to execute by doing `./ex.sh`.

```
new File('ex.sh').writeAsStringSync(script_str);
```

Perhaps, I need to set [FileStat](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/be/dartdoc-viewer/dart:io.FileStat) to file. but i'm not able to find any APIs.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15078  As a work around in the meantime you could just run chmod via [Process.run()](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:io.Process#id_run).

Comment: @GregLowe Yeah. currently this function is not yet implemented. I'll try Process.run() instead. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried it but what if you try:

```
new File('ex.sh').writeAsString(script_str).then((final File file) {
    return file.stat().then((final FileStat stat) => stat.mode = 777);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. but sadly `mode` is final variable. It seems there's no implementation to set `FileStat` :( https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/blob/7cf5e8497e1cdad03213f8d46b6c99582fbb7eb1/dart/sdk/lib/io/file_impl.dart

Comment: @SunggukLim you can create Native Extension https://www.dartlang.org/articles/native-extensions-for-standalone-dart-vm/

Answer (score 1):

It seems this function is not yet implemented.
See code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15078

As workaround, just made a utility function to run `chmod` command.

```
void _runBashCommandSync(GrinderContext context, String command, {String cwd, bool log: true}) {
  context.log(command);
  ProcessResult result =
    Process.runSync('/bin/bash', ['-c', command], workingDirectory: cwd);
  if (!log) return;
  if (result.stdout.isNotEmpty) {
    context.log(result.stdout);
  }
  if (result.stderr.isNotEmpty) {
    context.log(result.stderr);
  }
  if (result.exitCode > 0) {
    context.fail("exit code ${result.exitCode}");
  }
}
_runBashCommandSync(context, 'chmod 777 ex.sh');
```